# Cannot read property 'Types' of undefined -- using mongoose Schema.Types.ObjectId

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

**What is the current behavior?**

To run the script, I'm using `babel-node` since the script uses es6.

`Cannot read property 'Types' of undefined`

```
authorId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
                                   ^
```

**If the current behavior is a bug, please provide the steps to reproduce.**
I've defined the schema like this:

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const RecipeSchema = new Schema ({
  authorId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  name: String,
  description: String,
  photos: [
    {
      name: String,
      path: String,
      isMain: Boolean,
      alt: String
    }
  ],
  ingredients: [
    {
      name: String,
      quantity: Number,
      metricType: {
        type: String,
        enum: [ 'kg', 'g', 'mg', 'l', 'ml', 'unit' ],
        default: 'unit'
      }
    }
  ],
  preparement: String,
  isForSell: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: false },
  price: Number,
  url: String,
  portionNumber: Number,
  time: Number,
  grades: [
    {
      user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
      grade: Number,
      date: Date
    }
  ],

} );

export default mongoose.model ( 'Recipe', RecipeSchema );
```

And tried to seed the database with a function like this:

```
async function insert_recipe () {

  const user = await User.findOne ( {} );

  await Recipe.create ( {
    authorId: user.id,
    name: 'some name',
    description: 'some description',
    ingredients: [
      {
        name: 'foo',
        quantity: 12,
        metricType: 'g'
      },
      {
        name: 'bar',
        quantity: 50,
        metricType: 'g'
      }
    ],
    preparement: 'how to do something like this',
    isForSell: false,
    portionNumber: '5',
    time: 20
```

**What is the expected behavior?**
It should use the first user's ID that owns the recipe and create the recipe itself on the database.

**Please mention your node.js, mongoose and MongoDB version.**
I'm using the last versions for all of them in the current moment. (2017-09-15)

Comment: Are you actually running with `babel` or `typescript`? Which? `import` is not enabled for nodejs, so you need to clarify by what means you are actually using it.

Comment: You also have an error in `grades` on the references to `'User'`. You marked the property as `type: String`, but earlier the same model is referenced with `ObjectId`. Since this means the `_id` field in the `'User'` model, then it should also be `ObjectId`. Not the present problem, but the next one you would come up against.

Comment: I'm using `babel-node` to run the script. I tried to put `type: String`, because I saw it in another post in stackoverflow. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few trials, I found a solutions with a bit change in the Schema code.

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';
import User from '../models/user';

const RecipeSchema = new Schema ({
  authorId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  name: String,
  description: String,
  photos: [
    {
      name: String,
      path: String,
      isMain: Boolean,
      alt: String
    }
  ],
  ingredients: [
    {
      name: String,
      quantity: Number,
      metricType: {
        type: String,
        enum: [ 'kg', 'g', 'mg', 'l', 'ml', 'unit' ],
        default: 'unit'
      }
    }
  ],
  preparement: String,
  isForSell: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: false },
  price: Number,
  url: String,
  portionNumber: Number,
  time: Number,
  grades: [
    {
      user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
      grade: Number,
      date: Date
    }
  ],

} );

export default model.call(require('mongoose'), 'Recipe', RecipeSchema);
```

So I'm basically importing `Schema` and `model` directly instead of using with `mongoose.Schema` or `mongoose.model`.

I also had to make a call with `model` in the end to reference `mongoose`, like `model.call(require('mongoose'), 'Recipe', RecipeSchema);`

Now everything worked fine.

Thanks btw!